# Can't join and select in Sequel -- PG::SyntaxError

Tags: sql, ruby, database, postgresql, sequel

I'm trying to rename a column at join:

```
    # ...............

    result = DB[:my_items1].join(:my_items2, id: :my_item2_id).
          select([Sequel[:my_items2][:name].as(:my_items_name), 
                  Sequel[:my_items2][:amount].as(:my_item2_amount)
          ])

    # ...............
```

Exception:

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT ("my_items2"."name" AS "my_item2_name", "...
                                         ^
:
```

Comment: What's your whole SQL statement?  I'm guessing it's the alias inside the subselect that's running afoul of Postgres...

Answer (score 3):

Dataset#select takes multiple arguments, not a single array:

```
result = DB[:my_items1].join(:my_items2, id: :my_item2_id).
      select(Sequel[:my_items2][:name].as(:my_items_name), 
              Sequel[:my_items2][:amount].as(:my_item2_amount)
      )
```